# Difference between *LK* in /etc/shadow and /usr/sbin/nologon in /etc/passwd

Tags: pam, passwd, shadow, nsswitch

What is the practical difference between setting `*LK*` in `/etc/shadow` and setting `/usr/sbin/nologon` in `/etc/passwd`?

When would we choose one over the other? When would we combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a value that is not a valid password hash, such as `*LK*` to the password hash field of `/etc/shadow` will block *all forms of password authentication*, but if the user has other authentication mechanisms (like fingerprints or SSH keys) configured, **they will still work**.

As a special case of this, `passwd -l <username>` will prefix the existing hash with a single exclamation mark, so it is easy to undo with `passwd -u <username>`. Other invalid values such as `*LK*` can be used to indicate that a user account is not meant to be ever used for authentication, e.g. because the account is used to run some system service in a context that has no special privileges nor is associated with any particular human user.

Refer to `man 5 shadow`:

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

Likewise, `man passwd` includes this note on the `-l` option (lock the password) on modern distributions:

> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key). To disable the account, administrators should use usermod --expiredate 1 (this set the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).

(Aaron D. Marasco's suggestion that it disallows login and all forms of authentication *used to be correct*, but the semantics were changed within the last 10 years or so, in order to have a uniform way to disable password authentication but still allow the account to be used for other forms of authentication. This has tripped up many people in the past: there are a lot of books and other documentation around with outdated information on this.)

Setting the user's shell to something that is not an interactive shell, such as `/bin/false` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` will disable *shell access*, but if the user account is usable in other ways that use password authentication (e.g. for IMAP email access or FTP file transfers), **those can still work**.

So in a nutshell:

- to block all forms of authentication to login to or otherwise use an user account on both old & new systems, use `usermod -e 1 <username>`
- to disable shell access but allow other services, set user's shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, `/bin/false` or something similarly non-interactive.
- to disable password authentication but allow other authentication methods to work, use `passwd -l <username>` or other methods to set the password hash to an invalid value.
- to indicate to other sysadmins that the user account has been intentionally disabled with extreme prejudice, apply all of the above :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first would never allow that user to log in *nor ever authenticate* (the `*LK*` is not special AFAIK' it's just an invalid password hash). Meaning if you wanted to allow the system to have a valid password for something else like a webpage protected by `.htaccess`, that wouldn't work.

The second allows a valid user and password combination, but doesn't allow login. This would allow things like SFTP to upload a personal webpage, etc.